# Pegando dados json

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, json

Criei um json com os dados de uma revista que mantenho, só que agora tenho que criar um indice separado pela devida categoria, por autor, e os outros campos,
consegui pegar os dados gerais, mas não consigo filtrar esses dados para seu campo correspondente, vou mostrar o meu código e explico melhor.

```
var json = 
[
  {
        "ID":"7337",
        "TÍTULO":"ssss",
        "TIPO":"sssss",
        "NATUREZA DO TRABALHO":"",
        "CATEGORIA":"fdf",
        "SETOR EDUCACIONAL":"Educação Superior",
        "AUTORES":[
              {
                    "AUTOR":"wewew",
                    "INSTITUIÇÃO":"wewewe"
              },
              {
                    "AUTOR":"weew",
                    "INSTITUIÇÃO":"Ureerr"
              },
              {
                    "AUTOR":"sdsds",
                    "INSTITUIÇÃO":"Unicrerear"
              }
        ]
  },
  {
        "ID":"8265",
        "TÍTULO":"sddssd",
        "TIPO":"fdf",
        "NATUREZA DO TRABALHO":"Pesquisa",
        "CATEGORIA":"fdf",
        "SETOR EDUCACIONAL":"Educação Superior",
        "AUTORES":[
              {
                    "AUTOR":"teste",
                    "INSTITUIÇÃO":"Universidade de Ribeirão Preto"
              },
              {
                    "AUTOR":"teste",
                    "INSTITUIÇÃO":"Universidade de Ribeirão Preto"
              }
        ]
  },
  {
        "ID":"6216",
        "TÍTULO":"POLÍTICA",
        "TIPO":"testests",
        "NATUREZA DO TRABALHO":"textte",
        "CATEGORIA":"A - Estratégias e Políticas",
        "SETOR EDUCACIONAL":"Educação Superior",
        "AUTORES":[
              {
                    "AUTOR":"Araci Hpan",
                    "INSTITUIÇÃO":"UNIVERSIDADE "
              },
              {
                    "AUTOR":"Kelly",
                    "INSTITUIÇÃO":"Universidade "
              }
        ]
  },
  {
        "ID":"5869",
        "TÍTULO":"A EDUCAÇÃO BRASILEIRA E OS AVANÇOS NO PROCESSO DE REGULAMENTAÇÃO DO ENSINO A DISTÂNCIA",
        "TIPO":"Investigação Científica (IC)",
        "NATUREZA DO TRABALHO":"A - Planejamento ",
        "CATEGORIA":"A - Estratégias",
        "SETOR EDUCACIONAL":"Educação Superior",
        "AUTORES":[
              {
                    "AUTOR":"JAMARA C",
                    "INSTITUIÇÃO":"ISERJ"
              },
              {
                    "AUTOR":"sasa",
                    "INSTITUIÇÃO":"ewew"
              },
              {
                    "AUTOR":"s",
                    "INSTITUIÇÃO":"z"
              },
              {
                    "AUTOR":"z",
                    "INSTITUIÇÃO":"s"
              },
              {
                    "AUTOR":"Renata ",
                    "INSTITUIÇÃO":"Guia "
              },
              {
                    "AUTOR":"Almddjo",
                    "INSTITUIÇÃO":"FGF- Faculdade"
              }
        ]
  },
];

for(var i=0;i< json.length; i++){
 var html = "<tr>";
 html +="<td>"+json[i].ID+"</td>";
 html +="<td>"+json[i].TÍTULO+"</td>";
 html +="<td>"+json[i].TIPO+"</td>";
 html +="<td> <a href='trabalhos/"+json[i].ID+".pdf'>" +json[i].ID+"</td>";
 html +="</tr>";
 $('table tbody').append(html);
```

}

O que eu precisava seria filtrar isso, por exemplo todos que tenham a mesma categoria, todos que tenham o mesmo setor e assim por diante e mostrar no html, mas não estou conseguindo, se alguém puder me dá um help com esta questão

Answer (score 1):

O seu JSON é um array, você pode criar seu próprio helper, ou usar o método filter. 
O método filter recebe um argumento que é uma função de callback, essa função será chamada uma vez para cada item do seu array, e você deve retornar true caso o item pertença ao filtro, ou false caso não pertença, ou seja:

```
var livrosFdf = json.filter(function(livro) {
    return livro.CATEGORIA === "fdf";
});
```

Ou com arrow function:

```
var livrosFdf = json.filter(livro => livro.CATEGORIA === "fdf");
```

Para pesquisar por autor você precisaria fazer uma segunda consulta no array de autores:

```
var livrosKelly = json.filter(livro => livro.AUTORES.some(autor => autor.AUTOR === "Kelly"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Com esse código, você consegue organizar as categorias por exemplo, porém não sei exatamente se é esse o caminho que tu deverias seguir.

```
//source https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960473/get-all-unique-values-in-a-javascript-array-remove-duplicates
function onlyUnique(value, index, self) { 
  return self.indexOf(value) === index;
}

var categorias = json.map(function(item){
  return item.CATEGORIA
}).filter( onlyUnique );

var jsonSeparadoPorCategorias = {};

categorias.forEach(function(item){
 jsonSeparadoPorCategorias[item] = json.filter(function(i){
  return i.CATEGORIA === item;
 });
});

console.log(jsonSeparadoPorCategorias);
```